# Access GtkTreeView from GtkEntryCompletion

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtk3

Can I access the GtkTreeView associated with a GtkEntryCompletion? I'd like to connect to the [`move-cursor`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-move-cursor) signal to trigger a function whenever the user presses <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> to change the highlighted match.

The [description](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html) of GtkEntryCompletion indeed says, "GtkEntryCompletion is an auxiliary object to be used in conjunction with GtkEntry to provide the completion functionality. It implements the GtkCellLayout interface, to allow the user to add extra cells to the GtkTreeView with completion matches."

(I thought I might be able to do this with the [`cursor-on-match`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html#GtkEntryCompletion-cursor-on-match) signal for the GtkEntryCompletion itself, but I can't get that signal to fire no matter what I try. I'm using the Ruby bindings, if that makes any difference.)

Comment: `"cursor-on-match"` gets fired only if you do `gtk_entry_completion_set_inline_selection (True)`